# Firebase security hasChild(auth.uid) on same level rule denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want a branch to be secured by a list of admins at the same level in Firebase, but I keep getting denied. As an example;

```
conversations:{
  $cid:{
    messages:,
    admins:
    }
  }
```

I want to have a rule like;

```
"conversations":{
  "$cid":{
    "messages:{
      ".read":"root.child('conversations/$cid/admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",          
      ".write":"root.child('conversations/$cid/admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting access denied when I try to read messages when the user's uid is a child of admins.

Does my question make sense? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
Here's an actual database, but conversations has been changed to chapters and messages has been changed to gigs;

[image: database image]

My simulation;
[image]

Comment: Can you show the [minimal code that reproduces the read operation that fails](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I was just doing a simulated read of /conversations/$cid/messages/$mid/data in the firebase console. The simulation shows I can't read. If I add new branch called /admin and add a node with my uid and change my read rule to ".read":"root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)" I can read.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the failing read? Preferably including the path, value, auth state and relevant `/conversations`.

Comment: Yes, some more context would be helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you have enough information now?

Comment: Yup, thank you. I don't immediately see what's going wrong here though. :-/

Comment: The first thing I now note is that your security rules check against `root.child('conversations`, while your screenshots start with `/chapters`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The first post was just an example. The edit was real world example.